# Deixar item de lista sempre em primeiro de acordo com parâmetro recebido

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma página onde estou exibindo algumas galerias de foto, nessa página crio uma lista de forma dinâmica montando um menu, o que estou precisando e não estou conseguindo é quando um usuário entrar nessa página via URL com um parâmetro posicionar o item do menu que tem esse ID na primeira posição da lista, criei um `data-id` para ao criar a lista o item fique com o ID preenchido para ajudar no posicionamento.

Minha lista que está sendo usado como um menu está assim:

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-bordered list-group-noicon">                       
<?php foreach ($RelAlbum as $TituloGaleria) {
      $IdAlbum = $TituloGaleria->IdAlbum;
      $Titulo = $TituloGaleria->Titulo;
      $DataAlbum = $TituloGaleria->DataAlbum;
?>                                      
    <li class="list-group-item" data-id=<?php echo $IdAlbum ?></l>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:BuscaDados(<?php echo $IdAlbum ?>)"><i class="icon-camera"></i> <?php echo $DataAlbum ?> - <?php echo $Titulo ?></a></li>

<?php } ?>
```

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, se tivesse mais parte do código ajudaria, mas visualizei mais ou menos.

Talvez assim ajudaria?

```
//melhor dentro de uma tag jQUery Ready
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $id = "<?=$_GET['id'];>"; //supondo que está recebendo o id do album assim
  
  $tmpd = $("li").data($id).find("a.dropdown-toggle"); //guarda o <a...
  $tmpl = $("li").data($id); // guarda o <li...
  $tmpu = $("li").data($id).closest("ul"); //Guarda o local do menu.

  $("li").data($id).find("a.dropdown-toggle").remove(); //remove primeiro o <a
  $("li").data($id).remove(); //depois remove o <li
  
  $tmpu.prepend($tmpd); //adiciona primeiro o <a
  $tmpu.prepend($tmpl); //em seguida adiciona o <li
  

});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela grande ajuda, grande abraço @Jean Kássio

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).